# Eclipse - associate file to an editor without extension

Tags: eclipse, development-environment, code-formatting

I am writing a JavaScript app and set up a very pleasing code formatting (I like it old school style) styles so I feel comfortable while working.

My js files have to be named this way: **file_namejs** -> **without** the dot.

1. Is it possible to associate an extension missing file with an editor in eclipse?
2. If not, can you recommend another tool that enables high customization of the code formatter?

Thanks.